# Search Console Api 403 user does not have sufficient permission

Tags: python, api, google-search-console, google-api-python-client

I am using the following code, to get klicks, impressions, ctr and position from a given domain.

```
import argparse
import sys
from googleapiclient import sample_tools
import json

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('property_uri', type=str,
                       help=('Site or app URI to query data for (including '
                             'trailing slash).'))
argparser.add_argument('start_date', type=str,
                       help=('Start date of the requested date range in '
                             'YYYY-MM-DD format.'))
argparser.add_argument('end_date', type=str,
                       help=('End date of the requested date range in '
                             'YYYY-MM-DD format.'))

def main(argv):
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'webmasters', 'v3', __doc__, __file__, parents=[argparser],
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly')

  request = {
      'startDate': flags.start_date,
      'endDate': flags.end_date,
      'dimensions': ['query'],
      'rowLimit': 10
  }
  response = execute_request(service, flags.property_uri, request)
  print json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
  print_table(response, 'Top Queries')

def execute_request(service, property_uri, request):
  """Executes a searchAnalytics.query request.

  Args:
    service: The webmasters service to use when executing the query.
    property_uri: The site or app URI to request data for.
    request: The request to be executed.

  Returns:
    An array of response rows.
  """
  return service.searchanalytics().query(
      siteUrl=property_uri, body=request).execute()


def print_table(response, title):
  """Prints out a response table.

  Each row contains key(s), clicks, impressions, CTR, and average position.

  Args:
    response: The server response to be printed as a table.
    title: The title of the table.
  """
  print title + ':'

  if 'rows' not in response:
    print 'Empty response'
    return

  rows = response['rows']
  row_format = '{:<20}' + '{:>20}' * 4
  print row_format.format('Keys', 'Clicks', 'Impressions', 'CTR', 'Position')
  for row in rows:
    keys = ''
    # Keys are returned only if one or more dimensions are requested.
    if 'keys' in row:
      keys = u','.join(row['keys']).encode('utf-8')
    print row_format.format(
        keys, row['clicks'], row['impressions'], row['ctr'], row['position'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

The script works fine when i type in a domain (like www.example.de), which is listed in the web interface of search console. 
But when i try to get the values of another site, that's not listed in the web interface (perhaps www.example.de/sub_site), i get an error message, that i don't have the permissions for this. (On the Webinterface i have full permissions and can see the values)
The Problem is, i need only the values from the subsites. 
So my Question is, is this feature not enabled in the api or is there an error in my script?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `dimensionFilterGroups` and filter by `page` dimension - [example filter by country](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/searchconsole/search_analytics_api_sample.py#L105-L110). See also the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/searchanalytics/query#request-body).